# How do I fix this error GET http://localhost:8000/C:/Users/Dell/AppData/Local/Temp/phpDF8F.tmp 404 (Not Found)

Tags: laravel-livewire, laravel-10

I am developing a system using laravel with livewire, but for some reason I got this error

> GET http://localhost:8000/C:/Users/Dell/AppData/Local/Temp/phpDF8F.tmp 404 (Not Found)

in the console of my browser whenever I upload an image in a form, but when I submit the form, it works totally fine.

I tried searching on the internet but I can't find any solution. Does anyone know how to solve this?

This is my server-side code

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire\Admin;

use App\Models\Program;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;

class Programs extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;

    use WithPagination;

    protected $paginationTheme = 'bootstrap';

    public $program_id, $program_title, $display_image, $program_description, $program_created;

    public $paginate = 5;

    public $search = "";

    public function updatingSearch()
    {
        $this->resetPage();
    }

    public function resetInputs()
    {
        $this->display_image = "";
        $this->program_title = "";
        $this->program_description = "";
        $this->program_id = "";
        $this->program_created = "";
    }

    public function closeModal()
    {
        $this->resetErrorBag();
        $this->resetInputs();
    }

    public function add()
    {
        $this->validate([
            'display_image' => 'required|image',
            'program_title' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'program_description' => 'required|string',
        ]);

        $display_img_filename = $this->display_image->store('public/images/profiles/programs');

        Program::create([
            'display_img' => $display_img_filename,
            'title' => $this->program_title,
            'description' => $this->program_description,
        ]);

        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('close-modal');

        $this->resetInputs();
        $this->resetErrorBag();
    }

    public function view(Program $program)
    {
        $this->program_title = $program->title;
        $this->display_image = $program->display_img;
        $this->program_description = $program->description;
        $this->program_created = $program->created_at;
    }

    public function edit(Program $program)
    {
        $this->program_id = $program->id;
        $this->program_title = $program->title;
        $this->display_image = $program->display_img;
        $this->program_description = $program->description;
    }

    public function update()
    {
        $old_program = Program::find($this->program_id);

        if($this->display_image != $old_program->display_img){
            $this->validate([
                'display_image' => 'required|image',
                'program_title' => 'required|string|max:255',
                'program_description' => 'required|string',
            ]);

            Storage::disk('local')->delete($old_program->display_img);

            $display_img_filename = $this->display_image->store('public/images/profiles/programs');

            $program = Program::find($this->program_id);
            $program->display_img = $display_img_filename;
            $program->title = $this->program_title;
            $program->description = $this->program_description;
            $program->update();

        }else{
            $this->validate([
                'program_title' => 'required|string|max:255',
                'program_description' => 'required|string',
            ]);

            $program = Program::find($this->program_id);
            $program->title = $this->program_title;
            $program->description = $this->program_description;
            $program->update();
        }


        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('close-modal');

        $this->resetInputs();
        $this->resetErrorBag();
    }

    public function archiveConfirmation(Program $program)
    {
        $this->program_id = $program->id;
    }

    public function archive()
    {
        Program::find($this->program_id)->delete();
        
        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('close-modal');
        $this->resetInputs();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $programs = Program::where('title', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')
        ->orWhere('description', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->paginate($this->paginate);

        return view('livewire.admin.programs', ['programs' => $programs]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hard to say anything for sure without seeing your actual code.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information, I just updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I get it now why I am getting this error. It is because I'm using the same variable (`$display_image`) in my adding modal

```
<div class="row-auto mb-3">
  <label for="add-display-image" class="form-label">Display Picture</label>
  <input wire:model="display_image" id="add-display-image" type="file" class="form-control form-control-sm w-50" accept="image/*">
  @error('display_image') <span class="error text-danger" style="font-size: 0.8rem">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
</div>
```

And in my viewing modal:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
  <img class="object-fit-contain border rounded place-img" src="{{ Storage::url($display_image) }}" alt="">
</div>
```

So, when I try to upload an image, the code in my viewing modal will attempt to locate the temporarily uploaded image in my storage/public directory, which the temporary image is not stored at. So, to fix this, I must create a different variable where the temporary image will store, so that, the code from the viewing modal will not attempt to look for the temporary uploaded image. For example, I will create a `$add_display_image` variable dedicated for the adding modal. The code in my adding modal will look like this:

```
<div class="row-auto mb-3">
  <label for="add-display-image" class="form-label">Display Picture</label>
  <input wire:model="add_display_image" id="add-display-image" type="file" class="form-control form-control-sm w-50" accept="image/*">
  @error('add_display_image') <span class="error text-danger" style="font-size: 0.8rem">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
</div>
```